# How RDDs split Data for self?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm learning spark and got into one doubt.

Lets say I've 100 GB of file that needs to be processed. So I've created one RDD and partitioned into three parts. So three RDD will be executed in parallel on their respective nodes with their own set of data out of big input file. So far Good..!

If A part of data (Out of 100GB) is getting executing in node 1, B on node 2 and C on node 3.

Just want to know, Its a very big file, then how data gets distributed among three nodes..? For ex, A set of data from Big file to node 1 and B to node 3 and C to node 3. Does it reads a records wise or How it works ?

Please help me to understand..!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question...

Spark reading "splits" from the input data. Number of splits determined from the way the data is partitioned on your source path. This can be random number like 200 or the number of countries in the world if your data is partitioned by country.

When reading data into rdds, the partitions will be distributed between your nodes. It will extract all data from each partition.

Comment: I've 9 millions of records in Input single file. I want to know how data gets partitioned (3 million each for example). Because Its a single input file then how Spark hits 3 different portion of data in file at same time ?

Comment: If you have 9 millions records in just *one* file the "reading" will not be distributed between the nodes. There will be one node doing all the "reading"

Comment: So you mean to say, to process my all 9 million records of data, I should be having already three split files having 3 million records in it. Is it ?

Comment: Something like that...  The data should be partitioned when you reading it. It's better to work with CSV JSON Parquet files write it to HDFS s3 etc in some partitions (random number or partitions). Than reading will be distributed

Comment: Then what's a benefit of Spark...? :(

Comment: I think I'm missing on what is confusing you. The benefit of spark is the ability to distribute batch/stream computations on multiple machines. If your data is not distributed by itself spark will first read it than distribute your data manipulation across multiple machines and finally save it with multiple partitions. If the file is not spitted it means that one node will have to read it and distribute across machine only the reading part

Comment: Don’t you think so, distribution to other nodes and the putting into memory and then process...Will take same time as normal process does ...?

Comment: It's a trade off you pay a price for distribution. In memory computing is faster than distribution on any day. The distribution is a tool to cope with one machine limitations. Let's say that to do the task you want you need 100 cores and 1TB of memory. Do you have this kind of machine? probably no. So the only way to cope with this huge task is to distribute it between machines that you do have let's say 10 machine with 10 cores and 100 GB memory.